# Standard response to "homework" questions

Tags: support, comment, new-users, homework, low-quality-posts

Does there exist a boilerplate response to comment on questions that consists of a problem with no effort at a solution (as might be posed by a student posting a problem from a problem set)?

Comment: Are some suggestions from here along the lines of what you need: [List of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925)?

Comment: So, you want to reply to a question with no effort, with a comment with no effort?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, there is effort put in preparing the template. There is nothing wrong with this and it makes no sense to waste time typing a custom "we will not solve your homework" message every time.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I miss your point, or else you miss mine. Say, for example, someone posts "What is the derivative with respect to $x$ of $x^{2}$.'' Rather than give an answer, or down-vote the question, I would hope there's a way to reply considerately and informatively

Comment: There are many ways to reply considerately and informatively, kandb, and I prefer to come up with a new one every time the situation arises, so as to heighten the difference between what the asker has done and what I do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There is nothing inappropriate or inconsiderate in pointing the OP, with a carefully written template, to the ways they can improve their posts to get useful answers and a positive response from the community. The site is large, and it is up to each user to decide how they want to use their time. Many users are also not native speakers or advanced users of the language, so the task of coming up with new, original, considerate and informative custom phrased texts for each user may just be too much of an ask.

Comment: I usually use this template, where appropriate: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19973/42969, or this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9407/42969

Comment: If you can understand the question and also have time to give responses. It will be great to answer the question. Correct answers are always the necessary elements for learning. This is true for machine and also human learning. In the past, people considered figuring out the answer by students themselves as needed for learning. That is true for problems that don't have the correct answers, for example "is capitalism good?" However, that is inefficient for the problems that have the correct answers. This comment provides another view to responding to a problem with no effort at a solution.

Comment: Duplicating [my suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/19973#comment164422_4932) (which was adapted, with permission, from another user) here in case it gets accidentally deleted at its original site; its slight sternness is quite intentional:

Comment: `Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!`$\quad$